# Apex call-out 404 not found error on Developer console while it works perfectly when the request is sent through postman

Tags: rest-api, callout, apexrest, namedcredentials

This is the request, I've added the URL to named credentials. What am I doing wrong!!

```
Http http = new Http(); 
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); 
request.setEndpoint('Callout:AppointmentTest/services/data/v45.0'); 
String username = 'caseuser'; 
String password = 'Asdf123!';  
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password); 
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue); request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader); request.setMethod('PUT'); 
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
// Set the body as a JSON object 
request.setBody('{"SalesForceAccountID": "0014100000R7dJqAAJ", 
    "RecordType": "Appointment", 
    "AppointmentStatus":"Booked", 
    "AppointmentConfirmationStatus":"Escalated", 
    "ClientId":"BSHS", 
    "CaseId":"5008A0000045MUBQA2", 
    "CaseStatus": "Escalated", 
    "CallAttempts":1, 
    "MaxCallAttempts":2, 
    "CaseReason" : "Unable to reach - no answer", 
    "EscalationDate" :"2018-06-01 08:05:00", 
    "LastCallAttemptDate":"2018-06-01 08:02:00", 
    "NextCallAttemptDate":"2018-06-02"}'); 
HttpResponse response = http.send(request); 
// Parse the JSON response if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) { 
System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +    response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus()); 
} else { 
System.debug(response.getBody()); 
}
```

Comment: Well, answer is that you are sending a "different" request from salesforce -- it might be a extra character in body/url, or wrong auth, or extra header or another minor thing

Comment: I'm not sure if the setBody() works with just a String value.  Try using `Blob.valueOf(RequestJsonString)` in the `request.setBody()`

Comment: Is it salesforce endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's at least a couple of things wrong here.

```
request.setEndpoint('Callout:AppointmentTest/services/data/v45.0');
```

The endpoint `/services/data/v45.0` does not accept `PUT` requests or requests to create an sObject. If you're trying to call an Apex REST service class, it is definitely wrong: the endpoint for an Apex REST service starts with `/services/apexrest/` and then will include the URL mapping defined in the class.

If your Named Credential includes a path in its defined endpoint, appending this fragment to that URL will almost certainly produce an invalid endpoint leading to a 404 error. I suspect that's what is happening.

```
String username = 'caseuser'; 
String password = 'Asdf123!';  
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password); 
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue); request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
```

If you are using a Named Credential, it should be handling the authentication. This Basic Authentication header doesn't belong here.